# How to use preg_match when pattern has special symbol

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How do I implement preg_match() if my pattern has a symbol? My pattern is

```
"admin/filemanager"
```

what should be my preg_match syntax?

```
$line = "sometext/admin/filemanager/sometext";
(preg_match(??, $line, $matches))
```

Comment: I assume this is a simplified example? I ask because it appears to be a simple string search that doesn't require any regex functionality.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying To Find Forward Slash In Preg\_Match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239424/trying-to-find-forward-slash-in-preg-match)

Answer (score 1):

If you expect it to contain the delimiter character, just use a different character (one that won't appear in the pattern) for the [delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). E.g., `#pattern#` instead of `/pattern/`.

If you don't know what other special characters might be coming through, you can escape them with [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg_quote).

Answer (score 0):

It would be (for your example of course)

```
(preg_match("/[a-z\/]*/i", $line, $matches));
```

the /i is for case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution using [preg_quote()](http://php.net/preg_quote):

```
<?php

$pattern = preg_quote('#admin/filemanager#', '/');
$line    = 'sometext/admin/filemanager/sometext';

preg_match($pattern, $line, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

That solution is ideal if the haystack varies in its content, especially if it's a user-submitted haystack, and especially if it's going to execute frequently under lots of different use cases.

The better solution for a more controlled scenario where the haystack is consistent in its content and wholly owned by the developer is a properly formed [PCRE](http://php.net/pcre):

```
<?php

$pattern = '/admin\/filemanager/';
$line    = 'sometext/admin/filemanager/sometext';

preg_match($pattern, $line, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```